# Out of memory when using BitmapSource

Tags: c#, wpf, out-of-memory, bitmapsource

I'm changing source of a WPF image on run time with a frequency of 30ms ( 30 fps ). I'm getting an OutOfMemory.
In the following code, iImage is a private object displayed and owned by the wpf application.
bytes is a byte array readed and stored once at the creation of the window.

How can I avoid the outOfMemory ?
Is there a better solution to have a better performance to display a raw byte array ?

```
public void LoadBitmapImage(Byte[] bytes, Image iImage)
{  

  int bitsPerPixel = 24;
  double stride = (1024 * bitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
  BitmapSource wBitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(1024, 768, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null, bytes , (int)stride);      

  iImage.Source = wBitmapSource;

}
```

Thks

Comment: I'm not sure what cause the OutOfMemory Exception, but i wouldn't recreate the image all the time. Have a look at [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) which might suit your needs much better.

Comment: Thanks, by using WritableBitmap I avoid the OutOfMemory.

Comment: You could place `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` before calling BitmapSource.Create but that's more a hack than a solution.

Answer (score 0):

With the same code you can solve the memory problem by forcing garbage collection. For that place the below code above `BitmapSource.Create`.

```
//force garbage collection
System.GC.Collect();
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```